# What can I do when a post I've written receives a lot of spam edits?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, spam, faq-proposed

I wrote an answer to a question that was a paragraph and a half long, and it's been receiving a lot of edits from anonymous users that do nothing but introduce spam. This has been going on for a couple of weeks now, I'm sick of seeing this junk in my global inbox, is there some way I can get it to stop?

Someone said that adding more text to the post (it was a relatively short answer) might help, is this the case?

Answer (score 21):

For the most part, you don't have to do anything other than reject the edits as spam if they have not yet been rejected by others in the community. This will train our spam layer on the origins of the abusive edits, and the noise will soon stop.

**Don't** lessen the quality of your answer to try and stop this, we have a system in place so that it's not necessary to do so.

Note that as of March 2014, suggested edits rejected as spam on posts that are *known* spam targets [will result in an IP ban](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/7733/improve-filtering-of-spam-suggested-edits/7761?s=1|42.4991#7761). Additionally, as of April 2017, certain suggested edits rejected as spam [show up as fake 404 errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346541/can-we-get-a-lock-on-this-suggested-spam-edit-magnet-answer-please/346542), reducing the incentive for spammers to spam edits fully knowing that they get rejected.

***Hey, wait - I tried that and all, but it hasn't stopped, it's been weeks.***

If this is the case, then your post might be the target of a '[snow shoe](http://www.spamhaus.org/faq/section/Glossary#233)' spammer - one that uses a vast number of networks to try and inject a payload. We do monitor for this on a weekly basis and make some adjustments, but occasionally (depending on the size of the bot net trained on us) some stuff passes through.

If that's the case, [contact the community team](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) with the following information:

- The URL of the post (be it question or answer), just copy the 'share' link under the post to obtain this.
- How long this has been happening (so we can better scope a query)

Your ticket will then be assigned to someone familiar with the spam system that can run a query and make sure blocks are of an appropriate breadth.

Remember - *most* people won't see this annoyance and if you do, it generally only lasts a day, or a few days tops. Please give it at least a week before contacting us, or there might not be quite enough activity to dig through in order to block it effectively.

Comment: Is flagging for a moderator to lock the post for a little while not a good option?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I am a mod on the Windows Phone site and contacted Tim about this issue (hence his post). I had locked the answer for a week, but the spam came back as soon as the lock expired.